# Index a content folder into an exclude parent folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a global parent folder /files

I need to exclude his content so I put the line:

```
files/*
```

into the .gitignore.

But there is one folder "normal" (and of course is folders/files content) into, that I don't want to exclude.

I try to add the line:

```
!files/normal/*
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do that ? Thanks for help

.gitignore file:

```
vendor
files
!files/normal          # not work
.htaccess
.htpasswd
```

structure:

```
└───offres
    ├───normal
    └───unique
```

git status empty (just the .gitignore)

```
    modified:   ../.gitignore
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: It means that the content of "normal" folder is still ignore

Comment: try removing the `/*` from both rules.

Comment: files still ignore

Comment: Try to put *include* **before** *exclude*.

Comment: Please show your entire .gitignore file and sample directory structure. Also show the output of `git status`.

Answer (score 0):

Up until recently, ignoring a directory summarily and irreversibly ignored all its contents -- because ignoring a directory meant not looking at it, its contents were never matched against any (other) rules.  Now when you exempt a path, its parent directories are also exempted for the purpose of rules in that ignore file, but it looks like your version of git isn't that recent.

```
files/*
```

ignores everything in `files`, *including* the directory `files/normal`.  So, `files/normal` being an ignored directory nothing in `files/normal` is ever even tested -- all `files/normal/anything` rules simply never get a chance.

The usual all-purpose fix for this when the worktree isn't too sprawling is to just add

```
!*/
```

at the bottom of your .gitignore, which says "no matter what it says above, don't ever just entirely ignore a directory" and replace trailing `/*`s with `/**` to extend explicit wildcard ignore matches into the newly-unignored depths.  That's not the default because sometimes worktrees really are deep morasses, and scanning them uselessly can produce persistent, annoying speedbumps.

To fix this specific one, use

```
files/*
!files/normal
```

(or equivalently, at the bottom of your .gitignore, just put

```
!*/
```

and then after that explicitly list any directories you really do want to summarily and completely ignore)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but it seems I nothing understood at all, because everythink I try by your exemple failed. What should be the content of the .gitignore I my case ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
files/*              # excludes everything under dir `files`. Note that "/*" allows you to un-exclude a subfolder inside dir `files`       
!files/normal/       # un-excludes dir `files/normal` and (implicitly) everything under it.
```

If you don't put `/*` with directory `files`, the *un-exclude* won't work later.